# Positioning a fixed width div next to a floating "percent" div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've been around the block with my issues (not to sound like I'm some sort of whiny hoodlum); the thing that I'm having a hard time with is trying to figure out the best method to float two divs next to each other, one with a fixed width, and the other with a percentage width to fill the remaining amount.

My HTML Code is like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar">
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="tile">
                <h1>Catalogs</h1>
                <p>1</p>
            </div><!--
            --><div class="tile">
                <h1>Products</h1>
                <p>2</p>
            </div><!--
            --><div class="tile">
                <h1>Specifications</h1>
                <p>3</p>
            </div><!--
            --><div class="tile">
                <h1>New Products</h1>
                <p>4</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
```

And my CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
/* WEB FONTS

font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Francois One', sans-serif;

*/
body {
    background-color:#191919;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}
.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.sidebar{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    color:white;
    background-color:#191919;
    margin:0 auto;
    display: block;

}
.content{
    width: 80%;
    height: 1000px;
    float: right;
    color:white;
    background-image:url(Assets/background1.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.tile{
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color:white;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    transition: opacity 1s;
    opacity: .3;
    float: left;
}
.tile:hover {
    opacity: 1; 
}
.tile h1{
    font-family: 'Francois One', sans-serif;
    background-color:rgba(110,0,1,0.77);
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.tile p{

}
#item {
    padding-left: 25px;
    font-family: 'Francois One', sans-serif;
}
a {
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

This is my layout done in pure CSS. My problem is that I want my sidebar menu to have a fixed width of 400px and be next to content that fills the remaining space of 'x' pixels. If I shrink my page down enough, the text from the sidebar div over laps. That's why I want it to be fixed.

My solution to this problem was with jquery:

```
function widthAdjuster(wrapper, sidebar, content, tile){
    var wrapperWidth = $(wrapper).width();
    var sidebarWidth = $(sidebar).width();
    var newWidth = wrapperWidth - sidebarWidth;
    var newWidgetWidth = newWidth/4;

    $(content).css("width", newWidth);
    $(tile).css("width", newWidgetWidth);
}

function masterFunc(){
    widthAdjuster('.wrapper','.sidebar','.content','.tile');
    $(window).resize(widthAdjuster('.wrapper','.sidebar','.content','.tile'));
}
```

This will basically automatically set the width of content for me as well as adjust the width of each tile as well. Then on resize, it will re-run that function and size each of the tiles. Now, my question is, can I do this in CSS so that I don't have people yelling at me for using JQuery to adjust the width at Code Review?

Comment: If the solution to my problem requires the use of jquery, then please tell me. I will gladly use jquery to solve my problem. I've been told that what I'm doing can be solved without jquery, and that's why I'm looking for assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've achieved this before, change your css to this:

```
<style>
body {
background-color:#191919;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow:hidden;
font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}
.wrapper{
width: 100%;
min-height: 900px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.sidebar{
width: 20%;
height: 100%;
float: left;
color:white;
background-color:#191919;
margin:0 auto;
display: block;

}
.content{

height: 1000px;
float: right;
color:white;
background-image:url(Assets/background1.png);
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin:0 auto;
}
.tile{
width: 25%;
height: 100%;
display:inline-block;
margin: 0 auto;
color:white;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
transition: opacity 1s;
opacity: .3;
float: left;
}
.tile:hover {
opacity: 1; 
}
.tile h1{
font-family: 'Francois One', sans-serif;
background-color:rgba(110,0,1,0.77);
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
text-align:center;
line-height: 50px;
}
.tile p{

}
#item {
padding-left: 25px;
font-family: 'Francois One', sans-serif;
}
a {
color:white;
text-decoration:none;
}
.sidebar{
width:400px;
float:left;
margin:0 -400px 0 0;

}
.content{
position:absolute;
right:0;
left:400px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: That offsets the .content div off the screen and does not solve the issue at hand. However, you're on the right track, and with a little fiddling, I think I can get the problem solved.

Comment: I was hasty when I posted my answer, I didn't check what you were doing with your divs first, but my edited code above does do what you want it to do I think. If you just copy and paste it into your styles it should work.